# MySQL ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-insert

Consider the table marks:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM marks;
+--------+------------+-----------------------+
| name   | percentage | email                 |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+
| Bipin  | 84%        | bipin_p@gmail.com     |
| Deepak | 78%        | cool_deepak@gmail.com |
| Rohith | 82%        | rohith_s@gmail.com    |
| Sujit  | 94%        | sujit_jos@gmail.com   |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+
```

When I made the following query to insert values to the table, it resulted in an error:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO marks VALUES('&name','&percentage','&email');
ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'percentage' at row 1
```

It was done as an experiment based on info about another way to insert value using ('&') in SQL.

Can you specify what went wrong?
According to the blog, simply pressing ENTER will insert values after the query.

The desired output:

```
Enter value for name: John
Enter value for percentage: 76%
Enter value for email: john_doe@gmail.com
```

Comment: This Oracle feature is not supported in MySQL.

Comment: @GMB, I have zero knowledge of Oracle. Thank you for sharing that info. So just want to know such a feature exists in MySQL.

Comment: @Biping: as far as I know there is no such thing as a command prompt in MySQL.

Comment: That code is trying to put the literal string `&percentage` into the table.

Comment: @GMB Sure there is. Just run the `mysql` command from the shell, you get that prompt.

Comment: @GMB https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html

Comment: @Barmar I am running MySQL from MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client.

Comment: @Barmar: I was unclear. I mean command line popup, like the `&<varname>` in Oracle that generates an interactive prompt where the user can fill in the value. Does `msql` command line have that?

Comment: No, MySQL doesn't have that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MySQL, session variables are prefixed with `@`, and they're not expanded inside quotes. So it should be:

```
mysql> SET @name = 'John', @percentage = '76%', @email = 'john_doe@gmail.com';
mysql> INSERT INTO marks VALUES(@name,@percentage,@email);
```

There's no automatic prompt for variables like in Oracle, you have to set them by hand.